# Error when using "LID_USAGE" from the "swmm_api" package in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to extract individual LID settings for each subcatchment in SWMM using `LID_USAGE` from the `swmm_api` package. I have followed the example at https://markuspichler.gitlab.io/swmm_api/examples/how_to_add_LIDs.html, however, an error occurs. I wonder how to fix the code? I have attached the swmm model for your reference, thank you.

The **example SWMM model (input file)** is available at https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnVl_zW00EHemH5cu620m6vxqXdN?e=S5VSCA. I am using swmm-api 0.4.37.

```
from swmm_api import SwmmInput
from swmm_api.input_file.section_labels import SUBAREA,SUBCATCHMENTS,LID_CONTROLS,LID_USAGE
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

inp = SwmmInput.read_file('Example2.inp')
inp.LID_CONTROLS  # LID_CONTROLS works smoothly!
inp.LID_USAGE     # LID_USAGE is not working...
```

[image]

```
inp.LID_USAGE
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:780 in from_inp_line
    return cls(*line_args)

TypeError: __init__() takes from 8 to 12 positional arguments but 17 were given


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[6], line 1
    inp.LID_USAGE

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\inp.py:948 in LID_USAGE
    return self[LID_USAGE]

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\inp.py:193 in __getitem__
    self._convert_section(key)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\inp.py:214 in _convert_section
    self._data[key] = convert_section(key, self._data[key], self._converter)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:939 in convert_section
    return section_.from_inp_lines(lines)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:849 in from_inp_lines
    return cls.create_section(lines)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:831 in create_section
    sec.add_inp_lines(lines_iter)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:360 in add_inp_lines
    self.add_multiple(*self._section_object._convert_lines(multi_line_args))

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:866 in _convert_lines
    yield cls.from_inp_line(*line_args)

  File C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\envs\swmm\lib\site-packages\swmm_api\input_file\helpers.py:782 in from_inp_line
    raise TypeError(f'{e} | {cls.__name__}{line_args}\n\n__init__{signature(cls.__init__)}\n\n{getdoc(cls.__init__)}')

TypeError: __init__() takes from 8 to 12 positional arguments but 17 were given | LIDUsage('2', 'Bioretention', '1', '5000', '0', '10', '70', '1', '"E:\\Python', 'Examples\\SWMM', 'Calibration\\Example-Yang\\For', 'Calibration\\LID', 'Reports\\S2', 'Bioretention.txt"', '*', '0')

__init__(self, subcatchment, lid, n_replicate, area, width, saturation_init, impervious_portion, route_to_pervious=0, fn_lid_report=nan, drain_to=nan, from_pervious=nan)

Assignment of LID controls to subcatchments.

Args:
    subcatchment (str): Name of the subcatchment using the LID process.
    lid (str): Name of an LID process defined in the [LID_CONTROLS] section.
    n_replicate (int): Number of replicate LID units deployed.
    area (float): Area of each replicate unit (ft^2 or m^2 ).
    width (float): Width of the outflow face of each identical LID unit (in ft or m). This
        parameter applies to roofs, pavement, trenches, and swales that use
        overland flow to convey surface runoff off of the unit. It can be set to 0 for
        other LID processes, such as bio-retention cells, rain gardens, and rain
        barrels that simply spill any excess captured runoff over their berms.
    saturation_init (float): For bio-retention cells, rain gardens, and green roofs this is the degree to
        which the unit's soil is initially filled with water (0 % saturation
        corresponds to the wilting point moisture content, 100 % saturation has
        the moisture content equal to the porosity). The storage zone beneath
        the soil zone of the cell is assumed to be completely dry. For other types
        of LIDs it corresponds to the degree to which their storage zone is
        initially filled with water
    impervious_portion (float): Percent of the impervious portion of the subcatchment’s non-LID area
        whose runoff is treated by the LID practice. (E.g., if rain barrels are used
        to capture roof runoff and roofs represent 60% of the impervious area,
        then the impervious area treated is 60%). If the LID unit treats only direct
        rainfall, such as with a green roof, then this value should be 0. If the LID
        takes up the entire subcatchment then this field is ignored.
    route_to_pervious (int): A value of 1 indicates that the surface and drain flow from the LID unit
        should be routed back onto the pervious area of the subcatchment that
        contains it. This would be a common choice to make for rain barrels,
        rooftop disconnection, and possibly green roofs. The default value is 0.
    fn_lid_report (str): Optional name of a file to which detailed time series results for the LID
        will be written. Enclose the name in double quotes if it contains spaces
        and include the full path if it is different than the SWMM input file path.
        Use ‘*’ if not applicable and an entry for DrainTo follows
    drain_to (str): Optional name of subcatchment or node that receives flow from the unit’s
        drain line, if different from the outlet of the subcatchment that the LID is
        placed in.
    from_pervious (float): optional percent of the pervious portion of the subcatchment’s non-LID area
        whose runoff is treated by the LID practice. The default value is 0
```

.

Comment: Please post the traceback error as a text, and not a screenshot.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Hi, I just updated the question with details on the traceback error, thank you.

Comment: There should be unpacking problem as indicated error,  try not to unpack if it may work.

Comment: @root_coding Thank you for your reply. I wonder what you mean by "unpacking problem"? I installed the "swmm_api" package using pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message from the error says what the issue is:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 8 to 12 positional arguments but 17 were given
```

You are providing information that the program does not know how to parse, because it is only designed for 8-12 parameters. Why are you inputting 5 extra parameters- what are they for?

You are providing too many inputs for the input file. You can find details of the input file from the [documentation](https://www.epa.gov/sites/default/files/2019-02/documents/epaswmm5_1_manual_master_8-2-15.pdf) on page 296. These are the recommended parameters:

```
Subcat, LID, Number, Area, Width, InitSat, FromImp, ToPerv, RptFile, DrainTo
```

And here is an example of how the input could be structured for the input file:

```
[LID_USAGE]
;; assigning lid controls to subcatchments
;;Subcatchment   LID Process      Number  Area    Width   InitSat  FromImp  ToPerv  RptFile                 DrainTo  FromPerv
Sub1             BioCell          5       500     100     0        0        0       "example.txt"           *        0
```

**EDIT:**

The above comment was accurate, but the solution did not properly diagnose your issue. After looking at your files, you have filepaths like this for your RptFile:

```
"E:\Python Examples\SWMM Calibration\Example-Yang\For Calibration\LID Reports\S2 Bioretention.txt"
```

Shown here:

[image]

Python cannot properly interpret this kind of path and often incorrectly splits it into multiple lines; this is why you are getting an error regarding too many arguments. If Python interpreted this as a single path, you would not be getting the error.

So that's the solution: adjust the file paths to have no spaces, then copy-paste into your input file accordingly. I used this file path:

```
/Users/USER/Desktop/swmm_example/example.txt
```

and ran your code with no issues.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. For my original code `inp.LID_USAGE`, could you indicate how to structure the code to provide fewer inputs?

Comment: @YangYang you did not provide your input file, but if you do, I’d be happy to adjust accordingly. If you wish to do it yourself, you could find the section that has [LID_USAGE] as a header; the line that immediately follows is the one with too many inputs.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but I am still a bit confused. The example SWMM model (input file) is included in the question (on top of the example code section) for your reference. Could you suggest how to revise the code? Thanks.

Comment: @YangYang I have edited my answer to fix your problem. Also sorry, somehow missed the part where you provided your files- though typically, you should provide all relevant code in the question without leaving stack overflow. Let me know if this answer doesn’t suffice, Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your detailed reply. Removing the spaces in the file path has solved the error. I did not expect that spaces in the file path could lead to such an error, thanks again!